# Sufficient condition to inscribe a parallelogram inside another one

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, polygons

This question comes after another question I've asked [Sufficient condition to inscribe a polygon inside another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199999/sufficient-condition-to-inscribe-a-polygon-inside-another-one).

Given two parallelograms $P$ and $P'$ with vertexes respectively $x_1,\dots,x_4$ and $x_1',\dots,x_4'$, the condition $|x_i'x_j'|\le |x_ix_j|$ for all $i,j=1,\dots,4$ (i.e. all sides and diagonals of $P'$ are not longer than the corresponding sides and diagonals of $P$) is enough to conclude $P'\subset P$ (i.e. $P'$ can be moved by isometries in such a way to be entirely contained inside $P$)?

In my previous question user Misha showed a counterexample which clearly fails in case $P$ and $P'$ are both parallelograms

Comment: In case it helps: you can scale the $x$ and $y$ axes and translate so that one of the parallelograms is the unit square.

Comment: thank you, but I prefer to find a constructive procedure to inscribe $P'$ inside $P$ instead of scaling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can construct a degenerate parallelogram with side lengths 10 and 20 and diagonal lengths 10 and 30. It cannot contain a unit square.

Answer (score 1):

No, counter example:

[image]

The rhombus A'B'C'D' has the same side length as the unit square ABCD with. The diagonal of the rhombus is at most 2 =(2*side length), which is bigger than the diagonal of the square ($\sqrt{2}$). Thus the rhombus can never fit in the square.

Comment: To be a counter example, $2$ (the large diagonal of the rhombus) needs to be less than $\sqrt{2}$ (the corresponding diagonal of tge square).